# How is the recursion and control sturctures in this LISP code different from normal functions and control structures?

Tags: function, recursion, lisp

[image]

So this piece of code was on a worksheet that my teacher gave to prepare us for a recursion exam. The teacher states that in LISP, you write the operand before the variables, which makes enough sense. What doesn't make sense is that my prof says that the if block at line 2 is still read normally, "if y less than 1", but he says the code at line 3 executes when "y is not less than 1". The question on the worksheet asks us to find the result of f(3 2). Any answers to either question would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The if statement has three children: the test condition, the result when the test is true and the result when the test is false. In your code it might be confusing because the last two elements have been combined in line 3. The true result is simply '`x`', and the false result is `(f (* x x) (- y 1))`.
So the statement will be read as 'if y is less than 1 then return x, otherwise return `(f (* x x) (- y 1))`'.
I hope that's enough to get you started.